# Changing how URL parameters are appended to links based on destination

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

My company is serving up PPC landing pages with Unbounce (on a subdomain), which then links back to our website. We're using the following code to append the AdWords gclid variable to outgoing links:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {var params = window.location.search.replace(/\+/g,'%20'); var button = $('a').each( function(i) {this.href = this.href + params;});});
```

The issue arises when the Gclid gets appended to a URL that already has a parameter (like our checkout forms). You end up with a URL that looks like this:

```
domain.com/checkout?EventID=15546?Gclid=jdkI324kd
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to change the Glid's '**?**' to an '**&**' for certain URLs that already have parameters, while keeping the existing functionality of using the '?' for the others.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Seems like there's some redirection going on, this is how the href looks for the links in question: 
http://domain.com/lp/clkg/https/domain.com/cart.aspx?EventID=125160?gclid=CPfO1JaOx7oCFQZyQgod5A4AFw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace it yourself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var params = window.location.search.replace(/\+/g,'%20'); 
    var button = $('a').each( function(i) {
        if (this.href.indexOf('?') == -1) {
            this.href = this.href + params;
        } else if (params.length) {
            this.href = this.href + '&' + params.substr(1);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: and are you aware that you are replacing subsequent spaces with only one single '%20'?

Comment: Hm, I tried using your fix above and the GClid stopped getting passed at all, so the destination URL only contains the cart parameter.

Comment: I had one typo (`'&' . params.substr(1)` should be `'&' + params.substr(1)` of course), for the rest it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/TJ5p5/

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Can confirm the above snippet works like a charm!

Comment: That's the problem of programming in both PHP (where string concatenation is done with a dot) and in JavaScript (where string concatenation is done with a plus-sign). This wasn't the first time I made that fault ;)

Comment: Hey Peter, just to follow up, what's the issue with the spaces? This is code I got from Unbounce so I'm not sure what the issue is (if there is one).

Comment: Actually, there is nothing wrong with it. I mixed up two things in my head.